# Eclipse - jspf validation - Premature end of file

Tags: eclipse, jsp, validation, xhtml, jsp-fragments

I am porting my J2EE project from Eclipse Helios to Eclipse Kepler.
My project validates and works correctly on Helios, but, when moving it and all of its dependencies to Kepler I get this "Premature end of file" during the validation.
The file that causes the error is a simple JSPF file that is included in other JSP files.

This is the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see the full file except for DOCTYPE

Comment: This is the full file, it consists only in the doctype specification. The file is used only  to be included in other files.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
first of all, it's obvious that the file itself does not have any problem, so the solution is disabling the xhtml validation in Eclipse for jspf files:

- Open Preferences from the Window menu
- Select "Validation"
- Search for XHTML Syntax Validator and click on the Settings button
- Add an "Exclude Group"
- Add file extension "jspf" to this exclude group

Obviously this is the solution only if the problem is about the validation, if the file itself has some problem or is not well formed, this can't be the solution.